# Does a Canadian need a return ticket to enter Indonesia at Bali?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indonesia, canadian-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel

As a Canadian citizen flying from Australia to Bali, do I need to prove to the Australian airline at check in that I have booked a reservation out of Indonesia?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Canadian @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As of *today*, the [Canadian site on Travel](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/indonesia) does not mention that it is required to have a return ticket. It does say  immigration *can* require one while a passport *must* be valid for 6 months after arrival. That information was updated Jan 4, 2017, so it the most recent available now.**

It was certainly possible to travel there without a return ticket in 2012 as a Canadian. Bali specifically in my case as I arrived on a flight from Hong Kong to Denpasar. Many of the documents quoted are irrelevant to this situation since they are either intended for the UK or are regarding visa-on-arrival which does not apply since Canadians are granted visa-free entry. Of course rules may have changed since 2012 (I did not keep a copy), so what was possible then may does not necessarily apply to what is possible today.

**NOTE** Redacted and rewrote most of this answer to reflect information available today. Check this answer's history if you are curious.

Comment: Yes, that's why I pointed to the site which has a huge list of nationalities who are exempt from visas, which include 163 countries, so chances are, most people in the world is on that list :)

Comment: There you go, it's Canadian-specific now and I have first hand experience since I also went to Bali on a Canadian passport.

Comment: Additionally, [here](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/indonesia) is the official Canadian site on visiting Bali. As you can check, there is no return ticket requirement.

Comment: This answer is WRONG.  A return ticket IS needed.  See article 2(b) from this document - http://indonesianembassy.org.uk/en/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Minister-of-Law-and-Human-Rights-Regulation-No.-17-Year-2016.pdf  Note that the fact they may not ask to see the ticket isn't relevant - the fact is that they CAN.  Also, when the return is on the same ticket, the airline will have already notified them of the return details.

Comment: This is new (doc is from 2016). The requirements might have changed but I did do this a few years ago without return ticket.

Comment: @Doc - That's a document given to the UK embassy, someone also mentioned info shown at a UK site, but this question is for Canadians.

Comment: @itai It is a copy of the Indonesian regulations for visa free travel. Who gives it to you doesn't change the rules.  What happens "a few years ago" is irrelevant - especially given that at that time Canada wasnt on the visa free list (it was a paid visa on arrival, with different conditions)

Comment: @Doc - Possible, but they are free to send a different regulation to each country. I had not paid for a via either, so I have no idea where you got your info that it was not visa-free at the time.

Comment: Itai - the fact that your airline failed to check for your return ticket in 2012 does not mean it is not required today.

Comment: No but none of the documents shown say that it is required. See my latest edit. A valid passport for 6 months is required but not a return ticket as per information on the Canada government's site. That information was updated January 4th, 2017.

Comment: @Tom - No, they did not fail to check. They did not have to. Just because you think it is wrong, does not make the information available and updated as of 3 days ago any less valid!

Comment: Rewrote most of this to clear up based on the most recent information available today (Jan 4).

Comment: The Canada travel website says immigration can ask to be shown return tickets, which implies they are required but not always checked for.  The Indonesia embassy says they are required.  Timatic, which is THE most uptodate reference says they are required.  That is two at 100% yes, one at 50/50 yes versus Utai's one trip to Bali 4 years ago.  Yes rules.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Itai's answer, you are required to have a return or onward ticket.  So the airline could prevent you from boarding without one.  This is noted in Timatic, which is the reference the airline staff will check.

Immigration staff in Bali likely won't ask but they do have the right to check and deny entry if they wish.